# When I run rails server, it duplicates all my files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

When I run "rails s" in duplicates all my files. How do I run rails server? I created directory and decided to run rails server by running "rails s" but it just created the app files... which I already created with "rails new Raddit" Not sure what I did or what rails is doing since this is my first day at this

```
  create  app/controllers
  create  app/helpers
  create  app/models
  create  app/views/layouts
  create  config/environments
  create  config/initializers
  create  config/locales
  create  db
  create  doc
  create  lib
  create  lib/tasks
  create  log
  create  public/images
  create  public/javascripts
  create  public/stylesheets
  create  script/performance
  create  test/fixtures
  create  test/functional
  create  test/integration
  create  test/performance
  create  test/unit
  create  vendor
  create  vendor/plugins
  create  tmp/sessions
  create  tmp/sockets
  create  tmp/cache
  create  tmp/pids
  create  Rakefile
  create  README
  create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
  create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
  create  config/database.yml
  create  config/routes.rb
  create  config/locales/en.yml
  create  db/seeds.rb
  create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
  create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
  create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
  create  config/initializers/new_rails_defaults.rb
  create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
  create  config/initializers/cookie_verification_secret.rb
  create  config/environment.rb
  create  config/boot.rb
  create  config/environments/production.rb
  create  config/environments/development.rb
  create  config/environments/test.rb
  create  script/about
  create  script/console
  create  script/dbconsole
  create  script/destroy
  create  script/generate
  create  script/runner
  create  script/server
  create  script/plugin
  create  script/performance/benchmarker
  create  script/performance/profiler
  create  test/test_helper.rb
  create  test/performance/browsing_test.rb
  create  public/404.html
  create  public/422.html
  create  public/500.html
  create  public/index.html
  create  public/favicon.ico
  create  public/robots.txt
  create  public/images/rails.png
  create  public/javascripts/prototype.js
  create  public/javascripts/effects.js
  create  public/javascripts/dragdrop.js
  create  public/javascripts/controls.js
  create  public/javascripts/application.js
  create  doc/README_FOR_APP
  create  log/server.log
  create  log/production.log
  create  log/development.log
  create  log/test.log
  create  vendor/rails
```

Comment: You probably giving a `rails 3` command in `rails 2`.

Comment: I have rails 2.3.14 installed when I check

Comment: Then it is not the command for running server in `rails 2.3.14`.Give `ruby script/server`.

Comment: Oh great, now its running. Is there a way to get rails 3 on Linux or is it not stable?

Comment: Welcome to the future rails 3 is stable for many years. Right now in 2014 we use Rails 4.1. You should avoid installing rails with apt-get or yum but instead you should rather install rails with: gem install rails

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You did not set your rvm default,you need to run following commands.

source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm .

rvm use 2.1.3 --default

Comment: How does this answer the question?